# Porting libgdx game to iOS using Multi-OS engine - how to add Admob ads

Tags: libgdx, ios, xcode

I want to port my libgdx game to iOS using Multi-OS (RoboVM is no longer available). I've searched whole internet but can't find any info about how to use Admob with Multi-OS engine on iOS. Every resource I found is about RoboVM, but it's not available anymore since April 17 for new developers (you can only use it if you already have an account, but it's not possible to create a new one). Libgdx with Multi-OS is available in another branch on Github, but there is no info about ads and I want to publish my game this week. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can also try writing at the Libgdx forums - http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/